# How to save method returned mono in Reactor's Context to use it the next time the method is called in this reactor stream?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a method that returns data from some repo. Of course - these data can be changed at any given moment. I want to ensure that the data returned from the method remains consistent during a chain of operations (the method can also be called from another component during the chain). for example:

```
fetchDataThanCanBeChanged()
.flatMap(...)
.doOnNext(...)
.doOnSuccess(...)
.map(...)
.zipWith(...)
.flatMap(...)
.then(fetchDataThanCanBeChanged())......
```

I want to be sure that the second call to fetchDataThanCanBeChanged() returns the same data as the first.
I tried to wrap fetchDataThatCanBeChanged with method with Mono.deferContextual:

```
private Mono<Object> fetchDataUsingCache() {
   return fetchDataThatCanBeChanged()
      .flatMap(s ->
      Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> {
        System.out.println("cached snapshot=" + ctx.getOrEmpty("KEY")); 
        return Mono.just(s);
      }).contextWrite(ctx ->
          ctx.put("KEY", ctx.getOrDefault("KEY", s))
      ));
}
```

and call it twice:

```
fetchDataUsingCache()
.flatMap(d -> change(d))
.doOnNext(p -> saveChangedDataInRepo(p))
.delayElement(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
.fetchDataUsingCache()
.block();
```

but the content of fetchDataThatCanBeChanged() is only executed once and the returned data is the updated.

any idea for a solution???
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: did you consider `cache` operator?

Comment: @MartinTarjányi, thank you for your idea! just to be sure - is 'cache' unique per subscriber? if another user starts this chain before the prev one finished - he still should get the updated data from the repo and save it to his private cache, not the prev user data from cache.

Comment: That depends on the implementation of your code. You might need to take special care to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

finally I wrapped my code where I need the old fetched data with `Mono.deferContextual` and wrote the data to context like that:

```
fetchDataThanCanBeChanged()
   .flatMap(s -> Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> 
    changeDataInRepo()
    .doOnSuccess(b -> fetchDataThanCanBeChanged())
    .thenReturn(doWhateverNeedWithOldData(ctx.getOrEmpty("KEY"))))
  .contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put("KEY", s))))
.block();
```